# SSRS report data from 2 datasets

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS I am using 2 datasets to populate a table using "Lookup" function.  Data is returned by the 2 tables as following:

```
TABLE_A Data:   1,2,3,4   for date 12/01/2014

TABLE_B Data:   2, 4      for date 12/01/2014
```

When I run the report I want table to have the following:

```
                 TABLE_A        TABLE_B
12/01/2014        1              NULL

12/01/2014        2              2

12/01/2014        3              NULL

12/01/2014        4              4
```

But when Lookup function is used it is not showing data for 1,3 as data is not present in TABLE_B.

Can someone please help me on this issue.

Comment: What do you want it to show?   the word "NULL"?

Comment: Please post the expression you are using to do the Lookup.

Comment: You can use `IIF` expression on Lookup return value to check if it empty then assign the `NUll`